# Sort a python dictionary value which is a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following structure, how can I sort each list within itself in ascending order?

```
mydictionary = {'1':[1,4,2], '2':[2,1,3], '3':[1,3,2]}
```

I want to have the dictionary sorted like this:

```
mydictionary_sorted = {'1':[1,2,4], '2':[1,2,3], '3':[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: This is pretty basic, you are asking how to sort a list.

Comment: I am willing to answer if you show what you have tried and didn't work

Comment: Have you tried anything with `sort` (if you want to modify that dictionary) or `sorted` (if you want a separate one)?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> { x:sorted(y) for x,y in mydictionary.items() }
{'3': [1, 2, 3], '2': [1, 2, 3], '1': [1, 2, 4]}
```